# How does this code that tests for big- or little-endianness work?

Tags: c, endianness

I'm studying about Endianness and when I read a textbook they supplied me this run-time test to check (at run time) if the code is running on a little or big-Endian system. The book doesn't explain anything and I am left so confused how this code works. Can anyone please help me explain how this piece of code works. Thank you in advance

```
/* Test platform Endianness */
    int bigendian(void) {
        int i;
        union {
            char Array[4];
            long Chars;
        } TestUnion;
        char c = 'a';

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        TestUnion.Array[i] = c++; 
    if (TestUnion.Chars == 0x61626364)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify which part is unclear.

Comment: I don't really understand why we have to have a union for char Array and Chars as well as how the for loop works in this situation. The book just throws me this code and for a beginner i'm super confused

Comment: So you don't understand a simple for loop??

Comment: Yes I do. I just don't understand what exactly the role of the for loop in this code

Comment: Then in reality you have problems with the next line... and everything else is clear (what it does, not why)?

Comment: I do understand how for loop works, just don't understand how to apply it to this situation. I'm a beginner so I just have issue wrapping my head around abstract ideas. The book doesn't explain anything but give me this code so I just want to know the logically reason behind it or how they come up with this piece of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working on a system that uses ASCII for its character set, the values `0x61`, `0x62`, `0x63`, and `0x64` represent the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, respectively.

The loop:

```
char c = 'a';

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    TestUnion.Array[i] = c++;
```

Populates the `char array` part of the union `TestUnion` with `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.  If you're on a big-endian machine when you access the union as a 32-bit `long` it will be represented as `0x61626364`; if it was little-endian the long would be `0x64636261`.

This isn't a good "general case" algorithm to test for endianness, though, because:

1. Not all systems use ASCII to represent characters
2. A `long` is not necessarily `4*sizeof(char)` bytes wide

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

`union` provides different views of the data - here `TestUnion` can be interpreted as:

- a `char[4]` array, or
- a `long` int

The `for` loop populates `TestUnion` as a `char[4]` array - note that character `a` has ASCII code `0x61` and `b` is `0x62` and so on. So the memory is filled with 4 bytes `0x61`, `0x62`, `0x63`, `0x64` each having address location in ascending order.

The `if` statement check if it's [BigEndian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) or not by interpreting `TestUnion` as a `long` int. If it's BigEndian then the `long` int number is read from left-to-right which translates to `0x61626364`. Otherwise it's LittleEndian, which would read from right-to-left, meaning `0x64636261`.

You can check that function in your system using code such as:

```
printf( "bigendian ? %s\n", bigendian() ? "true" : "false" );
```

Comment: The need for this explanation proves how bad the code is. Byte order is an integer storage/processing issue so characters need not ever been introduced. Also, two bytes is all that is needed to have an ordering of bytes so using more creates confusion. (And, there was an assumption made about the size of long.)

Answer (score 2):

Endianness means whether the low byte or the high byte is stored first in memory. Little endian machines store the low byte first, big endian ones store the high byte first. If integers have more than two bytes, other orders are possible but are vanishingly rare.

What the code is doing is setting up a union, so that a char array and a long integer share the same address space. It then checks to see which way round the bytes of the long are, by calculating the expected value. It is poorly written for many reasons. Technically it's undefined behaviour to write to one field of a union then read from another. The code assumes that `sizeof(long) == 4`, that ASCII is the character set, and that the compiler will treat the union as expected. Probably all these will hold. He's also comparing a signed value to a hex value with the high bit set - I think that's OK but it rather depends on the minutae of the C standard.

A better test is simply

```
int x = 0xFF;
unsigned char *test = (unsigned char *)&x;
if(test[sizeof(int)-1] == 0xFF)
    /* big-endian */
if(test[sizeof(int)-1] == 0x00)
    /* little-endian */
```